# How do I get the value of a cell in a grouped CollectionView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I would prefer a solution in VB.NET but C# is also very welcome.

I have a ObservableCollection which I group. The groups can be expanded and collapsed. Each group has a different amount of rows with multiple cells. I want to sum the value of a single cell for every row of each group. This is for your imagination so that you can follow my thoughts.

Group A Total amount: "Cell#0 = 55" - "Cell#1 = 70"

```
Row#0 |-- Cell#0 = 25 --|-- Cell#1 = 50 --|

Row#1 |-- Cell#0 = 35 --|-- Cell#1 = 20 --|
```

Group B Total amount: 0

Group C Total amount: "Cell#0 = 12" - "Cell#1 = 8"

```
Row#0 |-- Cell#0 = 12 --|-- Cell#1 = 8 --|
```

Group D Total amount: "Cell#0 = 150" - "Cell#1 = 99"

```
Row#0 |-- Cell#0 = 25 --|-- Cell#1 = 33 --|

Row#1 |-- Cell#0 = 75 --|-- Cell#1 = 33 --|

Row#2 |-- Cell#0 = 50 --|-- Cell#1 = 33 --|
```

Here is a short code example so that you can try it out yourself if you want.

I have a class libary which I call Models. This libary contains a class called ProjectCompletedModel.vb

```
Public Class ProjectCompletedModel
    Public Property SomeColumnToGroup As String
    Public Property SomeValueToSum As Double
End Class
```

Next I have a class libary ViewModels. It contains the class ProjectCompletedViewModel.vb

```
Public Class ProjectCompletedViewModel    
        Private _projCompl As New ProjectCompletedModel

        Public Property Projects As ObservableCollection(Of ProjectCompletedModel)

        Public Property SomeColumnToGroup As String
            Get
                Return Me._projCompl.SomeColumnToGroup
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                Me._projCompl.SomeColumnToGroup = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property SomeValueToSum As Double
            Get
                Return Me._projCompl.SomeValueToSum
            End Get
            Set(value As Double)
                Me._projCompl.SomeValueToSum = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New()
            Me.SetProjects()

            Dim view As CollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.Projects)
            view.GroupDescriptions.Clear()
            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(New PropertyGroupDescription("SomeColumnToGroup"))
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription("SomeColumnToGroup", ListSortDirection.Ascending))
        End Sub 
    End Class
```

The code for my view is the folowing:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <!-- Define the Grid design -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Margin="0,52,0,0" 
                  Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">

            <!-- Define the column names -->
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="SomeColumnToGroup" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SomeColumnToGroup}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="SomeValueToSum" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SomeValueToSum}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

            <!-- Define the group style-->
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF425C8F" FontSize="14"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="(" FontSize="14" Foreground="#FF425C8F"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" Foreground="#FF425C8F" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text=")" Foreground="#FF425C8F" FontSize="14"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Finally the .xaml.vb file:

```
Public Class ProjectCompletedView

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.DataContext = New ProjectCompletedViewModel
    End Sub
End Class
```

My application has a reference to ViewModels. ViewModels to Models.

This is what it looks like with random values:

[image: Prototype]

**My approach**:

I managed by following the debugger to reach the cells so I did the following:

ProjectCompletedModel.vb does the grouping in the constructor. There I wanted to get the GroupNames.

- Ferrari
- Lamborghini
- Lotus
- etc

For each GroupName I wanted to loop through my ObservAbleCollection and see if the "ColumnName" matches the "GroupName". Then access the cell for the row where this condition is true. But I can't even get the GroupNames as the internal implementation is of this type which I can't retrieve any information.

[image: groupTypeInacessable]

Comment: Is there a question hidden somewhere inside the text?

Comment: The title might help you out.

Comment: @MatthisKohli It is fairly straightforward, I am doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a `Converter (eg; SumConverter)` to calculate the sum of the values.

Update your `TextBlock` in your `Expander.Header` to use this `Converter`.

Change `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" .../>` in your `Expander Header` to `<TextBlock Text="{Binding .,Converter={StaticResource SumCnvKey}}" .../>`.

Now your SumConverter will be called for every group.

```
public class SumConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CollectionViewGroup group = (CollectionViewGroup)value;            
        ReadOnlyObservableCollection<object> items = group.Items;
        var sum = (from p in items select ((ProjectCompletedModel)p).SomeValueToSum).Sum();

        return sum;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I created my own `ViewModel` with `Car` in a collection, and checked, it works fine.

[image: Group Sum Output]

See if this solves your issue.

Comment: You are my personal hero of the day! Your screen shot complies with what I want. I will implement it and give you feedback as soon as possible. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AnjumSKan It works! I had to apply small changes to my XAML file because I like to have everything ordered in namespace. So after importing that namespace correctly and adding the "SumConverter" to my "UserControl.Resources" I was able to bind my TextBlock to given converter as explained by AnjumSKan. Thank you very much!