# Customize groupheaders in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grouping, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to change the background color of my group headers depending on the value I give them to group after. All my datagrid rows have a "Category" column where I assign different textvalues and I would like to give group headers different colors based on the different values.

Picture of my groups right now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw2ob.jpg

Picture of how I want it to be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6mZq.jpg

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Retrieve the stackpanel that holds the GroupItems.
            StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)GetDescendantByType(listView1, typeof(StackPanel));

            //Retrieve the sencond GroupItem;
            GroupItem gi = sp.Children[1] as GroupItem;

            //Retrieve the Expander inside the GroupItem;
            Expander exp = (Expander)GetDescendantByType(gi, typeof(Expander));

            //Retrieve the Expander inside the GroupItem;
            Expander exp = (Expander)GetDescendantByType(gi, typeof(Expander));

            System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton tb = (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton)GetDescendantByType(exp, typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton));

            Border br = (Border)GetDescendantByType(tb, typeof(Border));

            //Change color;
            br.Background = Brushes.Red;
            br.UpdateLayout();
        }

        public static Visual GetDescendantByType(Visual element, Type type)
        {
            if (element == null) return null;
            if (element.GetType() == type) return element;
            Visual foundElement = null;
            if (element is FrameworkElement)
                (element as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
            {
                Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
                foundElement = GetDescendantByType(visual, type);
                if (foundElement != null)
                    break;
            }
            return foundElement;
        }
```

Source: [How to access group items of a listview in code-behind?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5496592d-20b7-4710-b568-a288cf9d3802/how-to-access-group-items-of-a-listview-in-codebehind?forum=wpf)

Answer (score -1):

Yo can try wrapping each other with border < Border Background="Black">

Answer (score -1):

See these answers, [WPF How to set DataGrid.Group header text when it's actually collapsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741830/wpf-how-to-set-datagrid-group-header-text-when-its-actually-collapsed/39742581#39742581)

[How do I get the value of a cell in a grouped CollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738132/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-cell-in-a-grouped-collectionview/38739917#38739917)

Apply the converter to the `Background` of your `TextBlock`, to change the color based on name.